# Question about sp_AllNightLog from Brent Ozar

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure it's the right channel for my question. I hope so. Does anyone have experience with sp_AllNightLog from Brent Ozar?. i installed it, but it doesn't create backups.

my stepps: 
1. installed Ola Hallengren’s Maintenance Scripts 
2. enable xp_cmdShell

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'xp_cmdShell', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

3. installing sp_AllNightLog, sp_AllNightLog_Setup, and sp_DatabaseRestor (no change in the scripts)
4. executed sp_AllNightLog_Setup:

```
sp_AllNightLog_Setup
  @RPOSeconds = 60,
  @RTOSeconds = 60,
  @BackupPath = 'B:\T_Backup',
  @RestorePath = 'B:\T_Backup',
  @Jobs = 2,
  @RunSetup = 1;
```

5. Jobs enabled: sp_AllNightLog_PollForNewDatabases and sp_AllNightLog_Backup_*

if i look in the folder B:\T_Backup then i don't see any files. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Are the backup jobs enabled? Are they succeeding? Did you look in the SQL Server Agent history?

Comment: the jobs: sp_AllNightLog_PollForNewDatabases, sp_AllNightLog_Backup_01 and sp_AllNightLog_Backup_02 are enabled. view job history is empty.

Comment: Ok, so the job history is empty, meaning they've never run. Are you sure the agent service is running? And that the schedule governing the jobs is enabled? What happens if you start a job manually? Do you see files in the output folder? Do you now see job history?